# Understanding of the acceptance rejection sampling algorithm

Tags: rejection-sampling

[image: Pls. check the steps below]Had some fundamental doubts about this algorithm.

1) Instead of trying to find another function g(x) and Uniform variable U , why can't we select random values of x and find f(x). 
That would generate random values as well .
2) What is the significance of choosing points which are below the curve of f(x) as determined by the ratio of f(x) and g(x)
We could as well ( for sake of randomeness) choose the ones which are above f(x) curve.

Thanks
Kedar

Comment: Please provide a quote or link to the text reproduced in the question.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As indicated in this [slide of mines](https://www.slideshare.net/xianblog/monte-carlo-statistical-methods-14772127), this algorithm produces valid simulations from the distribution with density $f$. This method has been [around for 70 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) and there is no doubt about its validity.

Concerning the proposals in the question

> Instead of trying to find another function g(x) and Uniform variable U
>   , why can't we select random values of x and find f(x). That would
>   generate random values as well

the meaning of "random" is not explicited. Which distribution should be used to simulate the $x$'s?  Looking at "random" $f(x)$'s does not return a sample from $f$.

And for

> What is the significance of choosing points which are below the curve
>   of f(x) as determined by the ratio of f(x) and g(x) We could as well (
>   for sake of randomeness [sic]) choose the ones which are above f(x)
>   curve.

the points $(x,u)$ below the curve of $kg$ are uniformly distributed over the subgraph of $kg$:
$$\mathcal S_g=\left\{(x,u); u\le kg(x) \right\}$$
and the resulting $x$'s are marginally distributed from $g$.

The points $(x,u)$ below the curve of $f$ are uniformly distributed over the subgraph of $f$:
$$\mathcal S_f=\left\{(x,u); u\le f(x) \right\}$$
and the resulting $x$'s are marginally distributed from $f$.

The points $(x,u)$ between the curve of $f$ and the curve of $kg$ are uniformly distributed over the set:
$$\mathcal S_r=\left\{(x,u); f(x)\le u\le kg(x) \right\}$$
and the resulting $x$'s are marginally distributed from
$$\dfrac{kg(x)-f(x)}{k-1}=r(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that rejection sampling is just one option and there are others.  Which method is best depends on circumstances and so finding an example where another option works better than rejection sampling is not hard.

Maybe a simple example will help you understand better.

Let's use $f(x) = 2 \times x$ for $0 < x < 1$ and 0 otherwise, $g(x)$ is uniform(0,1) and $k=2$.  A plot of this would be the rectangle between 0 and 1 on the x-axis and between 0 and 2 on the y-axis with a diagonal line from 0,0 to 1,2 representing $f(x)$.  The procedure is essentially choosing a uniform point within the rectangle (x coordinate comes from $g(x)$ and y coordinate from $k$ times the uniform).  If the point is in the lower triangle then it is accepted and if in the upper triangle then it is rejected.  Hopefully you can visualize (or graph it yourself) and see that this will produce more points close to 1 than close to 0.

If we instead accepted points greater than $k u$ then the result would choose more points close to 0 than to 1, which is the opposite of what we want to happen (this would actually generate points from $f(x) = 2-2\times x$).

For this simple case it is easy to find the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) and its inverse, so we could just select uniform(0,1) values and plug them into the inverse CDF to get values from $f(x)$.

But what about cases where the CDF and/or its inverse are hard or impossible to compute?  Rejection sampling can be preferable in those cases.

For this simple example we can use a uniform for $g(x)$, but what if we want to generate random observations from a distribution with infinite support?  Then we need a workable $g(x)$ with the same infinite support, the uniform over infinite support is not practical.

Choosing $g(x)$ and $k$ will influence the efficiency of the algorithm.  My example is 50% efficient.  Half the points will be accepted and half thrown away.  If we cannot find a $g(x)$ that is somewhat similar to $f(x)$ we could end up rejecting 90% or more of the points and the algorithm will take much longer to generate the desired sample size than if we find a combination of $g$ and $k$ where only 10% of the points are rejected.